# boolean from function is returning undefined node.js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

I have 2 functions... 1st one in `auth.js`, which does this:

```
 const adminCheck = (req, res) => {
    console.log(“one”)
    UtilRole.roleCheck(req, res, ‘ADMIN’, (response) =>  {
        if(response) {
             return true
         } else {
            return false
         }
     })
    }
    module.exports = {
    adminCheck
    }
```

basically checks if the user is an admin in my table. that works, but I am trying to retrieve the boolean in my function in my `index.js` function, which is below.

```
router.get(‘/viewRegistration’, auth.ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {

    console.log("authcheck: " + auth.adminCheck())

      const user = JSON.parse(req.session.passport.user)
      var query =  “SELECT * FROM tkwdottawa WHERE email = ‘” + user.emailAddress + “’”;

        ibmdb.open(DBCredentials.getDBCredentials(), function (err, conn) {
          if (err) return res.send(‘sorry, were unable to establish a connection to the database. Please try again later.’);
          conn.query(query, function (err, rows) {
            if (err) {
            Response.writeHead(404);
          }

           res.render(‘viewRegistration’,{page_title:“viewRegistration”,data:rows, user});

          return conn.close(function () {
            console.log(‘closed /viewRegistration’);

          });
          });
        });
    })
```

where I am logging the value in the console.log right under where I initialize the function, it is returning undefined. how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Promise and wrap all callbacks to actually return a given result value from a function that uses a callback because usually a callback is called asynchronously and simply returning a value from it does not help to catch it in a calling function.

```
const adminCheck = (req, res) => {
    console.log(“one”)
    return new Promise(resolve, reject) => {
      UtilRole.roleCheck(req, res, ‘ADMIN’, (response) =>  {
        if(response) {
             resolve(true)
         } else {
            resolve(false)
         }
     })
    }
  });
```

then you need to await a result calling this function using `await` keyword and marking a calling function as async:

```
router.get(‘/viewRegistration’, auth.ensureAuthenticated, async function(req, res, next) {

    console.log("authcheck: " + await auth.adminCheck())

      const user = JSON.parse(req.session.passport.user)
      var query =  “SELECT * FROM tkwdottawa WHERE email = ‘” + user.emailAddress + “’”;

        ibmdb.open(DBCredentials.getDBCredentials(), function (err, conn) {
          if (err) return res.send(‘sorry, were unable to establish a connection to the database. Please try again later.’);
          conn.query(query, function (err, rows) {
            if (err) {
            Response.writeHead(404);
          }

           res.render(‘viewRegistration’,{page_title:“viewRegistration”,data:rows, user});

          return conn.close(function () {
            console.log(‘closed /viewRegistration’);

          });
          });
        });
    })
```

Comment: Nothing indicates that the action is asynchronous.

Comment: @shaedrich, a callback itself indicates that we cannot get a result from a function immediately as its return value.

Comment: It might be a callback to report a progress while performing an operation but that's not the case here.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score -1):

That's simple. You just forgot to return the inner function's return value

```js
 const adminCheck = (req, res) => {
    console.log(“one”)
    return UtilRole.roleCheck(req, res, ‘ADMIN’, (response) =>  {
        if(response) {
             return true
         } else {
            return false
         }
     })
    }
    module.exports = {
        adminCheck
    }
```